# After deleting fluentbit pod and restarting it. Data is ingested all the data is ingested again there is no checkpoint for it to pick up new data

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, fluent-bit

fluentbit pod is not persistent every time I delete and start a new pod it indexes the all the data once again.

My deployment

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: deployment 
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: config_map_name
      configMap:
        name: config_map_name
    - name: pvc_name
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc_name       
  containers:
    - name: fluentbit-logger
      image: fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.3
      env:
        - name: FLUENTBIT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: user
        - name: FLUENTBIT_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: pwd              
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "32Mi"
          cpu: "50m"
        limits:
          memory: "64Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config_map_name
          mountPath: "/fluent-bit/etc"
        - name: pvc_name
          mountPath: mount_path  
  tolerations: 
    - key: "dedicated"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "sgelk"
      effect: "NoSchedule"

    - key: "dedicated"
      operator: "Equal"
      value: "kafka"
      effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Do I need to mount /etc/fluentbit directory to a storage class on AKS ? and which section of the yaml do I add it too.